# Correct way of passing array parameter in ethers

Tags: javascript, solidity, ethers.js

This is my function in solidity:

```
function mint(uint256[] memory tokenIds)
```

I am using `ethers` library to interact with contract so I am trying to use this function by using:

```
contract.mint([1,2,3])
```

but it doesn't work at all.
What is the correct way to pass array of elements to a method in `ethers`? I tried to pass string like `"[1,2,3]"` or `[1,2,3]` or even `["1","2","3"]` but none of those worked. On etherscan manually I can just pass `1,2,3` and it works fine

Comment: `[1, 2, 3]` is the correct way to pass an array. If it's not working, there's a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases (as happened in my contract too), the input must be parsed before sending it to the contract.

Example of smart contract function:

```
 function setServiceFees(uint256[] memory prices) public onlyOwner {
        require(prices.length == 4);
        serviceFees = prices;
    }
```

using the ethers.js, I did this and it worked.

Example of javascript code

```
myContract.setServiceFees([
        ethers.utils.parseEther(batchFee.toString()),
        ethers.utils.parseEther(easyFee.toString()),
        ethers.utils.parseEther(sellFee.toString()),
        ethers.utils.parseEther(forthFee.toString()),
  ])
```